# Keycloak / Angular - Always "invalid redirect_uri"

Tags: angular, keycloak

I have now looked through various questions & answers here, but cannot find a solution. The login and its redirect work perfectly. Only when I log in, I always get "invalid redirect_uri". The URL returns exactly the address of the service:

Service-URL: `https://subdomain.subdomain.xy-lab.ch`
Redirect-URI in URL: `https://subdomain.subdomain.xy-lab.ch/ (https://lernoase-auth.subdomain.xy-lab.ch/realms/Lernnomaden/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fsubdomain.subdomain.xy-lab.ch)`

I have tested all possible combinations of the URL in Keycloak. With and without HTTPS, "" "/" & "/*", etc. What could be the reason?

My Keycloak-Config for ln-frontend looks like this:

[image]

Angular I used [keycloak-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-angular) and is configured as follows:

```
// enviroment.json
const keycloakConfig: KeycloakConfig = {
  url: 'https://lernoase-auth.subdomain.xy-lab.ch/',
  realm: 'Lernnomaden',
  clientId: 'ln-frontend',
};

// keycloak-initializer.js
export function initializer(keycloak: KeycloakService): () => Promise<boolean> {
  const options: KeycloakOptions = {
    config: environment.keycloak,
    loadUserProfileAtStartUp: true,
    initOptions: {
      onLoad: 'check-sso',
      silentCheckSsoRedirectUri: window.location.origin + '/assets/silent-check-sso.html',
    },
  };

  return () => keycloak.init(options);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I am facing the same issue with the following versions:

- Angular: 14.x
- keycloak-angular: 12.x
- keycloak-js: 19.x
- keycloak: 19.x

As far as I understand keycloak introduced a new URL `post_logout_redirect_uri` param to follow Open ID connect guidelines. Make sure to also **set parameter** "**Valid post logout redirect URIs**" in your **client access settings** in the keycloak admin console.

Attached you will find a
[screenshot of admin console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CThvJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which keycloak version you are using, problems can arise if you enter the same redirect url in different formats.

you can try the following:

delete all valid redirect urls and set just one entry:

https://subdomain.subdomain.xy-lab.ch (I think it was for Keycloak >12)

https://subdomain.subdomain.xy-lab.ch/* (Keycloak < 12)

Otherwise, you can try to set the wildcard: * as redirect url to test if it is a configuration problem in your keycloak client. But please dont use the wildcard in production!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tested it again. Same result. Also with the wildcard "*". With "wrong" entries, the login does not work either. Then I correct them. Then the login works again, but the logout still shows the same error. I just don't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that the version of your `keycloak-js` dependency matches that one of Keycloak, for example `keycloak-js` version `18.0.1` matches Keycloak version `18.0.1`.

Credit goes to https://github.com/mauriciovigolo/keycloak-angular/issues/396#issuecomment-1117181820